# How to get output from Start-Process

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

How do you get the output from a command?

For simplicity:

```
$proc = Start-Process ls -PassThru -Wait -ArgumentList '-a' 
$OutPut = $proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

Error:

```
<Error retrieving property - InvalidOperationException>
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be that hard.  `$output = ls -a`

Comment: Thanks, but it was just for simplicity - I have way more for the ArgumentList :-)

Comment: Why would that matter?

Comment: Need to use double "--" in parameters and it looks like it only works with Start-Process

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Glad to hear, can you make this work: export IP_ADDRESS=$(kubectl get svc $INGRESSGATEWAY --namespace istio-system --output 'jsonpath={.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')

Comment: There's no export in powershell.  If this doesn't work, maybe you should post another question:  `$env:IP_ADDRESS = kubectl get svc $INGRESSGATEWAY --namespace istio-system --output 'jsonpath={.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'`

Comment: Thanks I know, but the question is simplified to break it down. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: And you are right, I should note what the overall  problem is - I will elaborate on this - thanks